# Which is the best way and most secure for pass sensitive data to WKWebView with Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

For my scenario, I have to use `WKWebview` for render some content but I want to authentication between my application and my webview first by use `accesss token`.

I have no idea how to pass token to wkwebview.

For my ideas now are

1. Pass with URL ( query param ) when load ( like google.com/content/29?access_token="something"
2. Use js to send access token to webview after loaded. ( this way has problem is Webview need to wait for set access token success before get content.)

Has anyone ever done this before ?

Comment: You can consider injecting your access token into your webview using `WKUserScript` with the `injectionTime` set to `.atDocumentStart`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will research about that.